# Show Custom Taxonomy Slug(s)?

Tags: customization, taxonomy

can anyone help me with this?

I need to print the slug of my custom taxonomy, can this be done?

The following kind of works but it just shows the name, rather than the slug which i need for a class purpose..

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'area' ); foreach( $terms as $term ) {print $term->name; unset($term);}?>
```

Any way of just getting the slug for my custom taxonomy 'area' ??

Many thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$term->slug
```

Here is an example return of $term:

```
 stdClass Object (
                  [term_id] => 31
                  [name] => Architectural Items / Salvage
                  [slug] => architectural-items-salvage
                  [term_group] => 0
                  [term_taxonomy_id] => 31
                  [taxonomy] => dcategory
                  [description] =>
                  [parent] => 5
                  [count] => 10
                  [object_id] => 197
                 )
```

If you don't know what's in `$term` or any other variable then [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) and [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) are your friend.